# How do I create a custom "Google Maps" visualisation from game map images?

Tags: maps, web, visualization

I am attempting to create the equivalent of a Google Maps map for a private Ultima Online server, with a custom map replacing the default map.

I'd like to allow players to pin important locations on the map and post screenshots of their play activity at a particular location.

I've seen this done in other games like Wurm Online. Does such a version of Google Maps (or a similar service) exist? Or would I have to build it myself?

Answer (score 1):

There is http://openlayers.org/ which should provide exactly what you need.

As seen in the example on http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/doc/quickstart.html it creates a scrollable map like google maps(but can do other types as well) and allows to place custom marker and overlays.

It does not help you with the map tile generation - it is only there to use map tiles and display them within the browser in a google-maps style.

Comment: This answer could be improved with a brief explanation of what makes OpenLayers the right tool here.

Comment: What if I write my game in a 2d engine in c++. How can I show map tiles there ?! possible ?

Comment: @EmAdpres: any game engine has some 2d buffers - just search the documentation for 2d-layered map and that should allow you do create a map. openlayers is for browsers since there you do not have such efficient low level control over mouse and graphics so speed and buffering is a major issue.